# Connect to Exchange Online with Powershell using Access Token

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication, exchange-server

I have acquired Access token and Refresh token from Azure AD. I need to connect to various O365 services from powershell using access token / refresh token. Can someone guide me how to proceed connecting to exchange server online.

Is there any other way we can connect to exchange server online using modern auth. I am using ExchangeOnlineManagement 2.0.3 version. I used below code-snippet based on the suggestion from the below listed blogs. I am getting error like "Password length is more than 256".

https://o365reports.com/2020/07/04/modern-auth-and-unattended-scripts-in-exchange-online-powershell-v2/

https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/1771/hacking-your-way-around-modern-authentication-and-the-powershell-modules-for-office-365

We need to automate the process but not able to connect to exchange using access token.

```
$AccessToken = <access-token-value>
$Authorization = "Bearer {0} " -f $AccessToken
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Authorization -Force
$UserCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("<upn-value>", $Password)
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $UserCredential -ShowProgress $true
```

Error Message: I am getting error that password length is more than 256 characters.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Comment: Could you please provide error message?

Comment: I have updated error message.

Comment: How did you get the access token? If you enter the username and password to get the access token, why not use them for `Connect-ExchangeOnline`? It appears to be not supported to use an access token to  `Connect-ExchangeOnline` directly.

Comment: I got access token from NodeJS using Passport Azure AD. I passed the access token to the shell script which internally uses Connect-ExchangeOnline. I also tried using ExchangeOnlineManagement 2.0.3 Preview but still getting error "Password length is beyond 256 chars"

Comment: Microsoft is going to remove Basic Auth and suggests everyone to use Modern Auth

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay.

I understand your requirement. I know using `New-PSSession` with Basic Authentication is going to be deprecated soon, so you are looking for an alternative.

But it's not supported to use an access token to connect to Exchange Online currently due to `AADSTS50052: The password entered exceeds the maximum length of '256'.`. I don't think you need worry about it. By then Microsoft should be able to provide coverage for all the functions that V1 modules have.

See a similar question [here](https://www.microsoftpartnercommunity.com/t5/Secure-Application-Model/Exch-Online-PowerShell-with-RefreshTokens-Secure-App-Model/m-p/25373#M206).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Refer to the article below, We need to install ExchangeOnlineManagement 2.0.3 version and connect using certificate. Follow the steps mentioned in the below post.

https://www.quadrotech-it.com/blog/certificate-based-authentication-for-exchange-online-remote-powershell/